# Transforming a Column into Multiple Columns according to Their Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I am wondering if there is a way to transform a one-column dataframe from this:
[image]

into this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source DF:

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]:
     Country
0      Italy
1  Indonesia
2     Canada
3      Italy
```

we can use [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
In [205]: pd.get_dummies(df.Country)
Out[205]:
   Canada  Indonesia  Italy
0       0          0      1
1       0          1      0
2       1          0      0
3       0          0      1
```

Or [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
In [211]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [212]: cv = CountVectorizer()

In [213]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(df.Country), 
                                 columns=cv.get_feature_names(), 
                                 index=df.index,
                                 default_fill_value=0)

In [214]: r
Out[214]:
   canada  indonesia  italy
0       0          0      1
1       0          1      0
2       1          0      0
3       0          0      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Couple of additional options

**`pd.Series.str.get_dummies`**

```
df.Country.str.get_dummies()

   Canada  Indonesia  Italy
0       0          0      1
1       0          1      0
2       1          0      0
3       0          0      1
```

---

**`pd.DataFrame.groupby` with `value_counts`**

```
df.groupby(level=0).Country.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

Country  Canada  Indonesia  Italy
0             0          0      1
1             0          1      0
2             1          0      0
3             0          0      1
```

---

**`pd.factorize` + `np.bincount`**

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Country.values)

pd.DataFrame(
    np.bincount(
        f + np.arange(f.size) * u.size, minlength=u.size * f.size
    ).reshape(f.size, u.size),
    df.index, u
)

   Italy  Indonesia  Canada
0      1          0       0
1      0          1       0
2      0          0       1
3      1          0       0
```

---

**`pd.factorize` + `np.eye`**

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Country.values)
pd.DataFrame(np.eye(u.size, dtype=int)[f], df.index, u)

   Italy  Indonesia  Canada
0      1          0       0
1      0          1       0
2      0          0       1
3      1          0       0
```

---

**`pd.factorize` + array slice assignment**

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Country.values)
a = np.zeros((f.size, u.size), dtype=int)
a[np.arange(f.size), f] = 1
pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, u)

   Italy  Indonesia  Canada
0      1          0       0
1      0          1       0
2      0          0       1
3      1          0       0
```