# Efficient way to do a kind of one-hot coding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684275/transforming-a-column-into-multiple-columns-according-to-their-values), but there is a difference: here instead of a single value, I have a list of values in one column of dataframe.

Let's say we have a pandas dataframe with one column named `words`. It contains the index of words which are available in a document. For example, in the following dataframe, there are two documents where the first one contains words `['a','b']` and the second contains `['a','c','d']`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['words'] = [['a','b'],['a','c','d']]
```

I want to convert the `words` column to different binary columns, one column for each word. The above dataframe will be converted to:

```
df['a'] = [True, True]
df['b'] = [True, False]
df['c'] = [False, True]
df['d'] = [False, True]
```

For now, I have the following code, where it iterates over different words `w` available in the `words` column.

```
df[w] = [w in word_list for word_list in df['words']]
```

Obviously, it is very slow. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: You may want to check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684296/5741205)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be using `get_dummies`

```
In [31]: pd.get_dummies(df.words.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0).astype(bool)
Out[31]:
      a      b      c      d
0  True   True  False  False
1  True  False   True   True
```

Another way, assuming you don't have `|` in the strings, or using any other separator

```
In [50]: df.words.str.join('|').str.get_dummies('|').astype(bool)
Out[50]:
      a      b      c      d
0  True   True  False  False
1  True  False   True   True
```

For single value.

```
In [68]: df['a'] = df.words.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)  # or ['a' in x for x in df.words]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is a nice answer. By the way, my dataframe has around 100M rows, and there are about 2000 distinct words. This is still very slow and maybe suffers from memory error. How can I generate the column for only one word such as `a`?

Comment: Updated the solution. And, for that large a data, storing lists in column is very inefficient.

Comment: It seems `df.words.apply` is not more efficient than what I mentioned in the question (and you added as a comment). About storing lists in a column, is there an alternative way?